# How to export daily disk usage to csv format in shell scripting?

Tags: linux, shell, csv, diskspace

My script is as below. When we run the script, it automatically saves the disk space usage in separate cells.

```
SIZES_1=`df -h | awk 'FNR == 1 {print $1","$2","$3","$4","$5","$6}'`
SIZES_2=`df -h | awk 'FNR == 2 {print $1","$2","$3","$4","$5","$6}'`
SIZES_3=`df -h | awk 'FNR == 3 {print $1","$2","$3","$4","$5","$6}'`
SIZES_4=`df -h | awk 'FNR == 4 {print $1","$2","$3","$4","$5","$6}'`
SIZES_5=`df -h | awk 'FNR == 5 {print $1","$2","$3","$4","$5","$6}'`
SIZES_6=`df -h | awk 'FNR == 6 {print $1","$2","$3","$4","$5","$6}'`
SIZES_7=`df -h | awk 'FNR == 7 {print $1","$2","$3","$4","$5","$6}'`
SIZES_8=`df -h | awk 'FNR == 8 {print $1","$2","$3","$4","$5","$6}'`
echo `date +%Z-%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S` >>/home/jeevagan/test_scripts/sizes/excel.csv
echo "$SIZES_1" >> /home/jeevagan/test_scripts/sizes/excel.csv
echo "$SIZES_2" >> /home/jeevagan/test_scripts/sizes/excel.csv
echo "$SIZES_3" >> /home/jeevagan/test_scripts/sizes/excel.csv
echo "$SIZES_4" >> /home/jeevagan/test_scripts/sizes/excel.csv
echo "$SIZES_5" >> /home/jeevagan/test_scripts/sizes/excel.csv
echo "$SIZES_6" >> /home/jeevagan/test_scripts/sizes/excel.csv
echo "$SIZES_7" >> /home/jeevagan/test_scripts/sizes/excel.csv
echo "$SIZES_8" >> /home/jeevagan/test_scripts/sizes/excel.csv
```

This script is okay for my machine.

My doubt is, if somebody else's machine has many file systems, my script won't work to fetch all the file systems usage. How to make it to grab all those automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want all filesystems you can simplify that to:

```
printf '%s\n' "$(date +%Z-%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S)" >> excel.csv
df -h | awk '{print $1","$2","$3","$4","$5","$6}' >> excel.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

I would simplify this to

```
{ date +%Z-%F_%H-%M-%S; df -h | tr -s ' ' ','; } >> excel.csv
```

- Group commands so only a single redirect is needed
- Squeeze spaces and replace them with a single comma using `tr`
- No need for `` echo `date` `` or similar: it's the same as just `date`
- `date +%Y-%m-%d` is the same as `date +%F`

Notice that this has a little flaw in that the first line of the output of `df -h`, which looks something like this originally

```
Filesystem          Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
```

has a space in the heading of the last column, so it becomes

```
Filesystem,Size,Used,Avail,Use%,Mounted,on
```

with an extra comma. The original awk solution just cut off the last word of the line, though. Similarly, spaces in paths would trip up this solution.

To fix the comma problem, you could for example run

```
sed -i 's/Mounted,on$/Mounted on/' excel.csv
```

every now and so often.

---

As an aside, to replace all field separators in awk, instead of

```
awk '{print $1","$2","$3","$4","$5","$6}'
```

you can use

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS = "," } { $1 = $1; print }'
```

or, shorter,

```
awk -v OFS=',' '{$1=$1}1'
```

Comment: For the header issue, just skip the first line with `sed -n '2,$ p'`