# disk space info to csv with date using cron job

Tags: linux, cron

Trying to get `df -h` output to a csv file via a cron job so I can setup a foreign data table and query it.

```
*/1 * * * * /var/lib/pgsql96 { date +%F_%H:%M:%S; df -h | tr -s ' ' ','; } > diskspaceinfo.csv
```

What am I doing wrong?

I have it set for once a minute so I can test it, but it never runs.

I am at `/var/lib/pgsql96 #` and I can manually run:

```
{ date +%F_%H:%M:%S; df -h | tr -s ' ' ','; } > diskspaceinfo.csv
```

and the `diskspaceinfo.csv` file in `var/lib/pgsql96` updates as expected.

Helpful links:

[How to export daily disk usage to csv format in shell scripting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38639064/how-to-export-daily-disk-usage-to-csv-format-in-shell-scripting)

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=59180

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

I also tried:

`@hourly /var/lib/pgsql96 { date +%F_%H:%M:%S; df -h | tr -s ' ' ','; } > diskspaceinfo.csv`

PS - bonus if you can put the date in front of each line output by `df -h` so it works nicely in csv/table format

Comment: try `*/1 * * * * { date +%F_%H:%M:%S; df -h /var/lib/pgsql96 | tr -s ' ' ','; } > /var/lib/pgsql96/diskspaceinfo.csv`

Comment: @mathB - that didn't work for me. Something else must be going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/var/lib/psgl96` isn't a command, it's a directory. You need to use the `cd` command to switch to it.

```
*/1 * * * * cd /var/lib/pgsql96; { date +\%F_\%H:\%M:\%S; df -h | tr -s ' ' ','; } > diskspaceinfo.csv
```

Comment: That didn't work. Something else must be going on. Does cron shut down if you modify it too much? I keep getting `You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/root`. In there I see `/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file` in the body of the message. I've checked several times. I have it in there like you have it. I tried mathB's suggestion too.

Comment: `%` has special meaning in `crontab`, it gets replaced with a newline. It needs to be escaped.

Comment: In general, you can save yourself lots of headaches if you put your code in scripts and then run the script from `crontab`.

Comment: Barmar - thanks on the `%` escape. Its working now! regarding script, I **now** couldn't agree more! That was my first `cron job`. What a beast (for a beginner).

Comment: The `%` thing is a very obscure feature, it catches many people, and I didn't remember it when I was first responding.

Comment: A script would be best of course, but without a script getting date into `df -h | awk '{print $1","$2","$3","$4","$5","$6}' > /var/lib/pgsql96/diskspaceinfo.csv` would make the data align with the headers. Otherwise you end up with "on" fromm the "Mounted on" header being in two different columns. (Note for the next guy.)